STM32f411CEU6 on BlackPill v3.1 via OpenOCD (interface: ST-LINK V2)
# openocd -f interface/stlink.cfg -f target/stm32f4x.cfg
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0+dev-00801-g133dd9d66 (2024-12-06-08:29)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "dapdirect_swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : STLINK V2J43S7 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:3748
Info : Target voltage: 3.275331
Error: init mode failed (unable to connect to the target)

How can I set the init mode?
Hints, informations and answers wished.
I would like to upload my program with a constructed OpenOCD-command.
Any suggestions for this purpose?
